# Webview rendering page different on different devices

Tags: android

My Webview setting for now is..

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        wv.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.setInitialScale(1);
        wv.getSettings().setUserAgent(1);
//      wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");
//      wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7");
//      wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
        wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.2; en-us; Galaxy Nexus Build/ICL53F) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

I am trying to load https://www.facebook.com/Nissan on my Phone SAMSUNG GALAXY S (OS 2.3.5)
and SAMSUNG NEXUS (4.0) it loads differently on both the phone..

it looks perfect on GALAXY S.. and create some prob on NEXUS 4.0 and not opening mobile view of page..

Already tried by supplying different user agent as listed and found some interesting results over
http://www.anandtech.com/show/5310/samsung-galaxy-nexus-ice-cream-sandwich-review/5

Still couldn't solve it. Let me know where I'm wrong..

The problem comes with SAMSUNG NEXUS (4.0) only..

Thanks.

Comment: If possible, please attach problem snaps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Paresh Mayani n All

succeed to reproduce the issue and solved..
changed a bit.. just removed User Agent String..
My current Webview Setting is..

```
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.setInitialScale(100);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

and added one line

```
wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

to support twitter profile URL.

Thanks.